# How to get an ec2 instance cost in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I launch an instance, stress it's cpu and delete the instance.

Using the aws cdk this takes a couple of minutes and I'm looping over 100
instance types (for benchmark purposes).

How can I get that instance's loop cost programmatically (aws cli or boto3)?

I have the instance-id

Comment: Cost explorer API, but the data there may be delayed.

Comment: Are you wanting to know the time it took to complete the CPU-intensive task? It would probably be easiest to have your 'stress' script record the time in some location (eg Amazon S3) before terminating the instance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The cost. Seems a rather exotic requirement here [cli doc](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage-with-resources.html)

Comment: The cost of an Amazon EC2 instance is based on the Instance Type and the time (in seconds) that it ran. Therefore, your script could record the duration and you could directly calculate the relative cost of each Instance Type, rather than attempting to retrieve it from the Billing records. Also, it is important that your program uses the full capabilities of each Instance Type (eg multiple threads taking advantage of all CPUs), otherwise the bigger instances will not provide any better performance.

Comment: And why all that effort to get the cost?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import boto3
import pprint

client = boto3.client('ce')

response = client.get_cost_and_usage_with_resources(
    Granularity='DAILY',
    Metrics=["BlendedCost", "UnblendedCost", "UsageQuantity"],
    TimePeriod={
        'Start': '2021-12-20',
        'End': '2021-12-28'
    },
    Filter={
        "Dimensions": {
            "Key": "SERVICE",
            "Values": ["Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute"]
        }
    },
    GroupBy=[{
        "Type": "DIMENSION",
        "Key": "RESOURCE_ID"
    }])

pprint.pprint(response)
```

Returns (shortened excerpt):

```
{'DimensionValueAttributes': [],
 'GroupDefinitions': [{'Key': 'RESOURCE_ID', 'Type': 'DIMENSION'}],
 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                                      'connection': 'keep-alive',
                                      'content-length': '8461',
                                      'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
                                      'date': 'Wed, 29 Dec 2021 09:08:16 GMT',
                                      'x-amzn-requestid': '2de9c92e-6d1c-4b1c-9087-bee17a41cb4f'},
                      'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
                      'RequestId': '2de9c92e-6d1c-4b1c-9087-bee17a41cb4f',
                      'RetryAttempts': 0},
 'ResultsByTime': [{'Estimated': True,
                    'Groups': [],
                    'TimePeriod': {'End': '2021-12-21T00:00:00Z',
                                   'Start': '2021-12-20T00:00:00Z'},
                    'Total': {'BlendedCost': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'USD'},
                              'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'USD'},
                              'UsageQuantity': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'N/A'}}},
                   {'Estimated': True,
                    'Groups': [],
                    'TimePeriod': {'End': '2021-12-22T00:00:00Z',
                                   'Start': '2021-12-21T00:00:00Z'},
                    'Total': {'BlendedCost': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'USD'},
                              'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'USD'},
                              'UsageQuantity': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'N/A'}}},
                   {'Estimated': True,
                    'Groups': [],
                    'TimePeriod': {'End': '2021-12-23T00:00:00Z',
                                   'Start': '2021-12-22T00:00:00Z'},
                    'Total': {'BlendedCost': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'USD'},
                              'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'USD'},
                              'UsageQuantity': {'Amount': '0', 'Unit': 'N/A'}}},
                   {'Estimated': True,
                    'Groups': [{'Keys': ['i-03ffa7c932a515d76'],
                                'Metrics': {'BlendedCost': {'Amount': '0.0027617772',
                                                            'Unit': 'USD'},
                                                            ....
                                                            ..
                                                            .
                                                            shortened here
                                                            .
                                                            .

                    'TimePeriod': {'End': '2021-12-27T00:00:00Z',
                                   'Start': '2021-12-26T00:00:00Z'},
                    'Total': {}},
                   {'Estimated': True,
                    'Groups': [{'Keys': ['i-0665a330b242714f2'],
                                'Metrics': {'BlendedCost': {'Amount': '0.216643501',
                                                            'Unit': 'USD'},
                                            'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0.216643501',
                                                              'Unit': 'USD'},
                                            'UsageQuantity': {'Amount': '0.554054168',
                                                              'Unit': 'N/A'}}},
                               {'Keys': ['i-080780d0d7e3394dd'],
                                'Metrics': {'BlendedCost': {'Amount': '2.7341269802',
                                                            'Unit': 'USD'},
                                            'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '2.7341269802',
                                                              'Unit': 'USD'},
                                            'UsageQuantity': {'Amount': '1.0241218603',
                                                              'Unit': 'N/A'}}},
                               {'Keys': ['i-0b95613810475903b'],
                                'Metrics': {'BlendedCost': {'Amount': '0.432736006',
                                                            'Unit': 'USD'},
                                            'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0.432736006',
                                                              'Unit': 'USD'},
                                            'UsageQuantity': {'Amount': '0.5530218935',
                                                              'Unit': 'N/A'}}},
                               {'Keys': ['i-0eab899e392cf4f35'],
                                'Metrics': {'BlendedCost': {'Amount': '0.5645311508',
                                                            'Unit': 'USD'},
                                            'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0.5645311508',
                                                              'Unit': 'USD'},
                                            'UsageQuantity': {'Amount': '1.1896368629',
                                                              'Unit': 'N/A'}}}],
                    'TimePeriod': {'End': '2021-12-28T00:00:00Z',
                                   'Start': '2021-12-27T00:00:00Z'},
                    'Total': {}}]}
```